# TinyMCE 5 - large images pasted via Safari do not render correctly

Tags: safari, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

We are running TinyMCE version 5.4.1 with various options including:

- paste_data_images: true
- powerpaste_allow_local_image: true

When we drag & drop (or paste) in smaller images (400px X 400px) everything seems to work fine. The Base64 encoding is saved to the database and the image is rendered from all browsers, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

However, when we paste in a larger image (1920px x 1081px) the image is only saved and rendered correctly in Chrome and Firefox. In Safari the Base64 encoding is saved with all lowercase characters. Therefore it doesn't render when attempting to view it. Has anyone else experienced this?

I have searched here as well as on the TinyMCE website but don't see anything mentioning this behavior. We will eventually attempt to move away from this Base64 implementation as it's no longer recommended but it's what we have for the time being so I'm just trying to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads, its' elements can do so in parallel. But when the browser sees the base64 image, it blocks the page from loading until this image is rendered. Thus, inserting large images into the page as base64 is certainly not a good practice - it may slow down page loads and worsen the UX.

To fix this problem and maybe several other issues, utilizing the [`automatic_uploads`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads) option is highly recommended. It will upload pasted images on the server instead of converting them to base64. Here is the example of the [PHP upload handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/) that will upload images and give their URLs back to TinyMCE.

Concerning the issue with Safari, some [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very useful.

I should also mention that PowerPaste is a premium feature that will not work with TinyMCE opensource. If you are using the paid version of TinyMCE, you can [create a support ticket](https://support.tiny.cloud/hc/en-us/requests/new).